# nginx reverse proxy subdomain is redirecting

Tags: nginx, proxy, redirect, reverse-proxy, git

So I have a frontend nginx server which will proxy to several other nginx servers (running Passenger for Rails apps).

Here's the part of the frontend nginx config in question:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name git.domain.com;
        access_log /server/domain/log/nginx.access.log;
        error_log /server/domain/log/nginx_error.log debug;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8020/;
        proxy_redirect     off;

            proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;

            client_max_body_size       10m;
            client_body_buffer_size    128k;

            proxy_connect_timeout      90;
            proxy_send_timeout         90;
            proxy_read_timeout         90;

            proxy_buffer_size          4k;
            proxy_buffers              4 32k;
            proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
            proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
        }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com;
    access_log /server/domain/log/nginx.access.log;
    error_log /server/domain/log/nginx_error.log debug;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
                proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header  Host             $http_host;
                proxy_redirect    off;
                proxy_set_header X_FORWARDED_PROTO https;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    }
}
```

Finally here's the backend for git.domain.com:

```
server {
        listen       8020;
        #server_name  localhost;
        root /server/gitorious/gitorious/public/;
        passenger_enabled on;

        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header  Host             $http_host;
        proxy_redirect    off;
        proxy_set_header X_FORWARDED_PROTO https;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

So here's the problem.  When I type in git.domain.com, my gitorious install will redirect to domain.com.  It works perfect there, but it ignores the subdomain.

At first I thought it was the `server_name` construct.  I have tried git.domain.com, domain.com, localhost, and currently none.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you will need to adjust proxy_redirect or some configuration in gitorious, can you snoop the frontend to backend request/response traffic to see the exact redirect gitorious is issuing ?

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the issues and forgot to close this.  You're right.  The frontend proxy_redirect command was wrong.  Commenting it out made everything else work.